# Kafka producer keeps producing messages even when only 1 node out of 3 is up

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Using kafka version 1.1.0 on the server and same spring dependency in the producer client:

Gradle dependency:
implementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.11', version: '1.1.0'

I have created a topic with replication factor 3 and single partition. Server side a 3 node kafka cluster. When all nodes are up the producer and send messages normally. When single node goes down, producer keeps working fine. When second node (out of 3) goes down, I am expecting the producer to throw exception as soon as  more than RF - 1 nodes are down. In this case it will 2 nodes.

Here is my java producer code.

Producer config:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers","host1:9092,host2:9092,host3:9092); 
props.put("min.insync.replicas","2");
props.put("default.replication.factor","3");
props.put("acks","all");
props.put("retries","1");
props.put("batch.size","16384");
props.put("linger.ms","1");
props.put("buffer.memory","33554432");
props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("num.partitions","1");
```

Sender code:

```
String data = "some data";
String topic = "testTopic";
try {
    ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
            topic, data);

    RecordMetadata m = producer.send(producerRecord).get(); // Publish message to topic

    logger.info("Message application id: {} ", appId);
    logger.info("Message produced, offset: " + m.offset());
    logger.info("Message produced, partition : " + m.partition());
    logger.info("Message produced, topic: " + m.topic());
    logger.info("Data sent to topic: {} ", topic);
}catch (Exception e) { 
    logger.error("Error:\n", e); 
    producer.close();
}
```

With above configuration and code, the producer can send messages with only one node up. I tried to narrow down the issue by using console producer "kafka-console-producer.sh" and I observe the same behavior. The console producer doesn't fail when 2 nodes are down.

Comment: What does this do with Spring? Looks like just plain Apache Kafka concern. More over you fully don't use Spring in your question. So, why confuse people? Thanks for understanding

Comment: Note: you can replace `kafka_2.11` with `kafka-clients` in Gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `props.put("min.insync.replicas","2");`

This is a topic and/or broker property, not a producer property.

Comment: Thanks Gary for pointing this out. This is the config we were looking for sometime. Once I created a topic with this config, I get the desired behavior (when 2 nodes out of 3 are unavailable then the producer gets an exception)